# USB Ports stopped working

Tags: usb

After I locked my screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (KDE keyboard shortcut that locks the screen) and went away for 5 minutes all the USB devices stopped working (mouse, keyboard & headset).

The devices are still disabled after reboot and I now get a load of error messages in my syslog:

```
Jun 13 09:30:04 robin-debian kernel: [  338.288104] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
Jun 13 09:30:04 robin-debian kernel: [  338.560074] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
Jun 13 09:30:05 robin-debian kernel: [  383.832047] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 100 using uhci_hcd
Jun 13 09:30:05 robin-debian kernel: [  383.956034] usb 7-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

These error messages keep popping up when my system is running. I've googled and searched on here and there weren't any working solutions in the results.

I'm running Debian Wheezy and using KDE.

Comment: Do the USB devices now work? What problem are you trying to solve? The messages appearing or the USB devices still not working? What does Ctrl+Alt+I do? I assume it is some kind of Gnome shortcut but what is it for those of us who don't use Gnome?

Comment: The USB devices work fine on other computers. I'm trying to get my USB devices to work again. The error messages are still coming.Ctrl+Alt+L locks the screen (KDE and probably also in Gnome)

Comment: OK, so the USB devidces are still not working in this computer even after rebooting. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've also tried some solution which involves enabling the old_scheme_first with the command:echo Y > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/old_scheme_first after that I rebooted again and it still gave me the same error message.